# I want to merge a Seq[Tuple2] and a Seq[String] to a Seq[Tuple3] in Scala

Tags: scala, merge, tuples, seq

Here is my solution, but I don't like it very much:

```
var seq1: Seq[String] = Seq("apple", "banana", "camel")
var seq2: Seq[(String, String)] = Seq( "green" -> "fruit", "yellow" -> "fruit", "brown" -> "animal" )
var iter = seq1.toIterator

seq2.map {s => (s._1, s._2, iter.next()) }
```

Comment: Remember: you should probably use `val`s instead of `var`s, and you don't need to indicate the types here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you find yourself doing much of this kind of thing, the [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library provides some really nice ways to work with tuples without giving up type safety.

For example, you could write the following using Shapeless's prepend operator for tuples (`+:`) and the standard library's `zipped`, which lets you avoid the creation of intermediate collections:

```
(seq1, seq2).zipped.map(_ +: _)
```

This is beautiful, type-safe, and for large collections it'll be more performant than solutions using `zip`.

You could of course also use `zipped` without Shapeless:

```
(seq1, seq2).zipped.map { case (a, (b, c)) => (a, b, c) }
```

Or:

```
(seq1, seq2).zipped.map((a, b) => (a, b._1, b._2))
```

In addition to the fact that this doesn't build an intermediate collection of tuples, the fact that `map` here takes a function of two arguments (instead of a function from tuples) can sometimes make the syntax a little cleaner (as you can see in the `+:` example above).

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
scala> var seq1 = Seq("apple", "banana", "camel")
seq1: Seq[String] = List(apple, banana, camel)

scala> var seq2 = Seq("green" -> "fruit", "yellow" -> "fruit", "brown" -> "animal")
seq2: Seq[(String, String)] = List((green,fruit), (yellow,fruit), (brown,animal))

scala> seq1 zip seq2 map { case (s1, (s2, s3)) => (s1, s2, s3) }
res1: Seq[(String, String, String)] = List((apple,green,fruit), (banana,yellow,fruit), (camel,brown,animal))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
seq2 zip seq1 map (x => (x._1._1, x._1._2, x._2))
```

Answer (score 0):

using [product-collections](https://github.com/marklister/product-collections)

```
seq2 flatZip seq1
res0: org.catch22.collections.immutable.CollSeq3[String,String,String] = 
CollSeq((green,fruit,apple),
        (yellow,fruit,banana),
        (brown,animal,camel))
```

A `CollSeq3` is a collection that holds only Tuple3[A,B,C]s and is itself a Tuple3[Seq[A],Seq[B],Seq[C]].